# Why treeview's item method doesn't work in this situation?

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a GUI program with Python tkinter. To achieve some function, in a `Toplevel` window, some event triggered a method of it which would call the `Treeview` widget's `item(ID, tags=(some_tag))` of the `Tk` window to change the style of `Treeview`'s content. But it doesn't work even if the snippet containing `.item()` have been run and no error occurs. My corresponding code snippet is as follows(some irrelevant part is omitted).

```
class Main_window(Tk):
    # some_code_omitted...
    def create_widgets():
        # some_code_omitted...
        self.tv1 = ttk.Treeview()
class A_Toplevel(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    # some_code_omitted...
    def some_foo(self, event):
        self.parent.tv1.item(ID, tags=(some_tag))
```

After some attempt, I found it seems that only when `tv.item()` is called in the `Main_window`, it works. later I wrote a method in `Main_window` to call `tv.item()`. But when the instance of `A_Toplevel` call it, it still doesn't work at all.

```
class Main_window(Tk):
    # some_code_omitted...
    def create_widgets():
        # some_code_omitted...
        self.tv1 = ttk.Treeview()
    def a_foo(self, ):
        self.tv1.item(ID, tags=(some_tag))
class A_Toplevel(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    # some_code_omitted...
    def some_foo(self, event):
        self.parent.a_foo()
```

What's wrong and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong in the code you posted.  [mcve], please.

Comment: What does "doesn't work at all" mean? Does it throw an error? Does it return the wrong data? Something else?

Comment: It means .item() method doesn't change the style of the Treeview's item. Actually, .item(ID, tags=(some_tag)) change the tag of the item, with which some special style is bound. However, this command run, and nothing changed as well as no error occurred.

Comment: Should `self.parent.tv1.a_foo()` be `self.parent.a_foo()` instead?

Comment: Thanks for correction. I didn't realize this editing error.

Answer (score -1):

Oh! Some progress.

Today, I found a way to solve it occasionally with `threading` module. Codes are as follows:

```
def a_foo_thr(self, ID, some_tag):
    thr = threading.Thread(target=self.a_foo, args=(ID, some_tag))
    thr.start()
def a_foo(self, ID, some_tag):
    self.tv1.item(ID, some_tag)
```

But I have no idea why it succeeded, even whether it could make some unexpected problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).